# Testing throttle with jasmine clock

Tags: javascript, jasmine, lodash, throttling

Is there currently a way to test lodash `_.throttle` using `jasmine.clock`? I found answers from 2015 where people are saying it's not possible, here is an example of what I found: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/361

My code looks something like this:

```
let methodTested =  _.throttle(() => callMethod, {trailing: true, leading: false }); // this method is imported

beforeEach(function() {
  methodTested();
  jasmine.clock().tick(100);
});

it('callMethod to be called', function() {
  expect(callMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I am using jasmine 2.2 and lodash 3.10

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

Lodash:

```js
'use strict';

const _ = require('lodash');

describe('foo:', () => {
  let now;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.clock().install();
    jasmine.clock().mockDate();
 
    // const nowTime = Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1); // 1483228800 * 1000, now
    // jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date(nowTime));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });

  it('bar', () => {
    const callMethod = jasmine.createSpy();
    const throttled = _.throttle(() => callMethod(), 100);

    const t = setInterval(() => {
       throttled()
    }, 50);

    jasmine.clock().tick(400);

    expect(callMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);

    clearInterval(t);
  });

});
```

Comment: I get the first call but then when I check if it was called second time after 100ms I don't get the second call

Comment: updated lodash sample (removed underscore one). It doesn't work for me if I commented out mocking date. But it works with it. Take a look

Comment: which lodash and jasmine versions are you using. I still can't get it to work

Comment: also when I put breakpoint within `setInterval` it passes. When there is no breakpoint and I do `{leading: false, trailing: true}` even with using tick I don't get the call to `callMethod`

Comment: I think this works because the throttle method is created after we mock the `jasmine.clock`. Because I am importing the method I think this won't work

Comment: if I put `callMethod ` and `throttled` initialization to the top (right below require lodash) it also works for me. Could you share your snippet of the code via gist or something like that?